# Can't submit a form using DataTables

Tags: jquery, forms, datatables, submit

I have a form and when I remove Datatables, it's working properly. But when I put `<table id='example'>` to use Datatables, it does not submit the form.  If I put `echo form_open` before ` it doesn't work properly, it inserts only teacher_id=13, but not different for the row, I've chosen. That's my view:

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.js">
<script src="../../media/js/dataTables.editor.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
         "bSort": true,
         "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        // "pagingType": "scrolling",
          
          "tableTools": {
    "sSwfPath": "http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
    "aButtons": [
  "csv",
  
  {
  "sExtends": "pdf",
  "sButtonText": "Print PDF",
  "mColumns": "visible"
  },
  "xls"

  ] 
 }


    } );
} );
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
        var title = $('#example thead td').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
    } );
 
    
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
 
    table.columns().eq( 0 ).each( function ( colIdx ) {
        $( 'input', table.column( colIdx ).footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            table
                .column( colIdx )
                .search( this.value )
                .draw();
        } );
    } );
} );
</script>
  <?php
echo validation_errors();


?>
<table id='example'>
  <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Teachers</th>   
     <th>Coord.</th>
     <th>Change coord.</th>
      <th>Deactivate teacher</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>  
  <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>Teachers</th>   
     <th>Coord.</th>
     <th>Change coord.</th>
      <th>Deactivate teacher</th>
        </tr>
  </tfoot> 
  <tbody>
    <?php   
foreach ($teachers_show as $teacher)
{
echo form_open('coordinator/deactivate_teacher');  
  ?>
  <tr>
  <td>
  <?php echo $teacher->username; 
?> 
  </td>
  <td>
  <?php echo $teacher->coordinator_id;  ?>       
  </td><td>
  <?php 
    echo '<a href="edit_coordinator/' . $teacher->user_id . '" class="btn btn-success" id="change_coord">  Change </a>';
?>
</td><td>
<?php 
echo "<input type='hidden' name='teacher' value='$teacher->user_id' />";
echo '<input type="submit" name="deactivate" value="Деактивирай учител" id="change_coord" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to deactivate?\'); " />';
?>
</td></tr>
<?php
echo form_close();

}

?>
 
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there error in the console

Comment: Might not be relevant, but you're missing a closing script tag on this line: `<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.js">`

Comment: I fixed it, but that's not the problem.

Comment: If you fixed it, it would be helpful if you showed us HOW you fixed it.